# R/exams: Open-ended text question in exams2blackboard

Tags: r, r-exams

Using `string` questions in `exams2blackboard()` from R/exams, is there a way to set the size of the box where students type in their answer in an open-ended question? Using `string` generates just a single row. The idea would be to have a text editor with a larger box for an open-ended text question.

Comment: The `string` type is intended for short closed-form text answers. Hence, there is only a small box. Some `exams2xyz()` interfaces support open-ended answers which can be entered into a multi-line text editor in the browser. However, I'm not sure whether this is the case for Blackboard. You can try with `exams2blackboard("essayreg.Rmd", ...)`. See <https://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/>. I have to ask my co-authors with access to Blackboard whether they can say more.

Comment: Here it is what I get: `Error in switch(if (!is.null(y)) y else x, mchoice = "Multiple Answer",  : 
EXPR must be a length 1 vector
Calls: exams2blackboard -> gsub -> bb_questiontype
Execution halted`

Comment: Ah, I see. In `exams2blackboard()` only a single `stringtype` is supported, i.e., you can use only an `essay` (like you want) OR a `file` upload but not both (as specified in `essayreg.Rmd`. Could you please try to make a copy of `essayreg.Rmd` (say `myessay.Rmd`) and edit the line specifying the stringtype to `exstringtype: essay`. Afterwards `exams2blackboard("myessay.Rmd", ...)` should work - but I wasn't able to check what it looks like in Blackboard. If it works, I'll post a more complete answer.

Comment: I have posted a proper answer now and also edited your question so that it can be found more easily by other users. Please accept my answer below (by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer) so that the question is flagged as resolved here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Overview**

Starting from R/exams version 2.4-0 (the current CRAN release at the time of writing), different types of `string` exercises can be easily distinguished:

- `string`: The default is a "closed" string questions where the participants typically enter a short string (e.g., a name of a function or method etc.). The answer entered then needs to match exactly the specified correct solution in order to obtain the point(s) associated with the exercise.
- `essay`: Alternatively, an open-ended text question can be used where participants enter an "essay" in a text editor in the browser. The presentation depends to a certain degree on the specific learning management system. Instructors need to assign points manually.
- `file`: Rather than providing the answer to an open-ended question in a text editor, participants can use a file upload (e.g., a PDF, HTML, Docx, etc.). Again, instructors need to assign points manually.

Some `exams2xyz()` interfaces (notably `exams2moodle()` and `exams2qti21()` and hence `exams2openolat()`) also allow the combination of several types, typically `essay|file` so that student have the text editor *and* file upload. This is illustrated by the [essayreg](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/) exercise template provided on the R/exams web page.

**Solution**

In order to use an open-ended essay question in `exams2blackboard()` you need to specify the following meta-information (here shown in R/Markdown style):

```
Meta-information
================
exname: [...]
extype: string
exstringtype: essay
exsolution: nil
```

where `[...]` should be a short description for your exercise.

**Example**

To try this out, please download the [essayreg](https://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/) exercise template and save it as `myessay.Rmd`. Then, edit the line specifying the `stringtype` to `exstringtype: essay` and run

```
exams2blackboard("myessay.Rmd", ...)
```